# Maximum number of work items, work groups within NDRange

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have the following system parameters:

```
CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
Device maximum compute units = 20
Device maximum Work Item Dimensions = 3
Device maximum Work Item Sizes = 512 x 512 x 512
Device maximum Work Group Size = 512
```

As I understand, if Item Dimensions = 1 -- there is an one-dimensional array of work-items in a work group. If Item Dimensions = 2 -- there is a two-dimensional array or matrix of work-items in a work group and so on. Work groups, in their turn, all together represent a set (NDRange). 
But I cannot understand how to:
1) determine the maximum number of work-items in array or in matrix inside a work group
2) determine the maximum number of work-groups elements inside a set

I tried to find similar questions and clear answers, but unsuccessfully. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Here I found basics explained and good illustrated with examples and pictures: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/cs575/Handouts/opencl.1pp.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just focus on the device maximum Work Item/Group limits.
Compute units is just for device fision functionalities.

The limits in work group size are given by:

```
Device maximum Work Group Size = 512
```

This is the maximum amount of work items in a work group. And it matches with the limit in the HW.

Then, you have to add an extra constrain to the "shape" of the group, in your case:

```
Device maximum Work Item Dimensions = 3
Device maximum Work Item Sizes = 512 x 512 x 512
```

Which means the limit is 3 dimensions, and in each dimension 512, so no limit for you! You can shape the 512 work items in the way you like `512x1x1` or `256x2x1`, etc...

However the limit could be ie: `16x16x16`. Therefore, even if you can run 512 in total, you are limited to `16x16x2`, `8x8x8` or `16x8x4`... etc. Not allowed values would be `32x16x1` or `512x1x1`.

*NOTE: It is not so uncommon to be limited by the shape. nVIDIA devices usually have 4096 work group sizes and `1024x1024x1024` limits.My guess is that they do it that way so they can store the work dimension id in a single register. While `4096x4096x4096` would need 2 registers.*

Comment: Thank you! It`s helpful.